# How to define the correct type for the Promise.all response iterable?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, axios, promise

As we know that the Promise.all will return settled promise in the same order of the requested iterable.

I am trying to understand how to put correct type for individual settled resolve.
I am using Axios to perform Asynchronous calls.

```
Promise.all([
   <void, A>call an API a with response type A,
   <void, B>call another API b with response type B,
   <void, C>call another API c with response type C
]).then(([
       Response aa of type A: ?,
       Response bb of type B: ?,
       Response cc of type C: ?
   ]) => {
});
```

All responses of are of type `AxiosResponse<A | B | C>`. But If I set it explicitly to that I would be facing issue when reading a property in one of the response type which is not there in the other. For example: complier will complain about `bb.test` if property `test` doesn't exist in `aa` or `cc`.

Is the following possible as it explicitly tells which type of individual response is?

```
]).then(([
       Response aa of type A: AxiosResponse<A>,
       Response bb of type B: AxiosResponse<B>,
       Response cc of type C: AxiosResponse<C>
   ]) => {
```

Note: The compiler is implicitly taking care of the types by the way.

Comment: Can you share your actual code, please? This should work, [`Promise.all` is declared to take a tuple type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/efc9c065a2caa52c5bebd08d730eed508075a78a/src/lib/es2015.promise.d.ts#L15-L24)

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the array as a literal like in your question, it should work. As Bergi writes in the comments, [`Promise.all` is declared to take a tuple type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/efc9c065a2caa52c5bebd08d730eed508075a78a/src/lib/es2015.promise.d.ts#L15-L24).

```
declare var a: Promise<A>;
declare var b: Promise<B>;
declare var c: Promise<C>;

Promise.all([a, b, c]).then(([a1, b1, c1]) => {
  (a1);
  //^? (parameter) a1: A
  (b1);
  //^? (parameter) b1: B
  (c1);
  //^? (parameter) c1: C
});
```

However, TypeScript will assume that if you declare an array, it will try to find a ["best common type"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#best-common-type) compatible with all the elements of the array. This interferes with your ability to destructure the array into specific types.

```
let array = [a, b, c];
//  ^? let array: (Promise<A> | Promise<B> | Promise<C>)[]

Promise.all(array).then(([a1, b1, c1]) => {
  (a1);
  //^? (parameter) a1: (A | B | C)
  (b1);
  //^? (parameter) b1: (A | B | C)
  (c1);
  //^? (parameter) c1: (A | B | C)
});
```

To keep the types but still use an array, you'll have to use the [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) `as const` to instruct TypeScript to treat it as a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), as it did in the first example.

```
let tuple = [a, b, c] as const;
//  ^? let tuple: readonly [Promise<A>, Promise<B>, Promise<C>]

Promise.all(tuple).then(([a1, b1, c1]) => {
  (a1);
  //^? (parameter) a1: A
  (b1);
  //^? (parameter) b1: B
  (c1);
  //^? (parameter) c1: C
});
```

See the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBDAXFAzsATgSwDsBzAXwG4AoUSKAIQWQCMNt9jyrxoBhBpAYxa5CpShQAmEfgBsUOaADc5UdFAAKOAPYBbPJggAeGAD5KkmXMXLm6rbv0HapiVNnyoSnFEG2dew9zOFBp++gB0KNLSABQA2igANFCMSfwAugCUYcAAFhAE0XEoAIxJjKXexZkIxsgUUFDRJRmUDQD0bQB6APz1jeUtfR09fdH8xYPtXb0kgxTSEMAqODgoIAzxZalplB0NI8F2-hFRTStrWbn5hfEV5alVGTV1DU0TrVDDva8DH1+j40mn2mFFmYgWS2AAFcwAsNolktsVJhvJoCNhdm19r1DqEICcYtDYRBLnkCkU7hVxtV4LUkKNmn8QT93kNmY1AUyRmCKEA) for the examples above.